# Drodownlist populated by db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have 2 dropdown lists one is for states and one is for cities. I am populating the states dropdown from the database which works fine. And I have a method that when the index changes on the states it populates the cities dropdown. Now for some reason when i change a state and the method hits the populateCity dropdown, it gives me an error saying

> Sqlexception error: invalid column name 'ME'

ME is just because i chose Maine, it will happen with every state i choose, under the da.fill(ds, "City"); not sure why it keeps doing that.

Here is the code for the states dropdown and city dropdown:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmdState = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT state,abr FROM tbl_zip ORDER BY state ASC", con);
        DataSet dsState = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter daState = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdState);

        con.Open();
        daState.Fill(dsState, "State");

        States.DataSource = dsState.Tables[0];
        States.DataTextField = "state";
        States.DataValueField = "abr";
        States.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void States_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (States.SelectedItem.Value != "Select")
    {
        string st = States.SelectedValue;
        PopulateCity(st);
    }
}

protected void PopulateCity(string st)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tbl_zip WHERE abr = " + st, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(ds, "City");

    Cities.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    Cities.DataTextField = "city";
    Cities.DataValueField = "city";
    Cities.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tbl_zip WHERE abr = '" + st + "'", con); You need the apos around st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Raphael mentionned, if `st` is a string then it needs quotes around or it will be invalid SQL syntax, another way to do it would be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tbl_zip WHERE abr = @State";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("State", st);
```

Answer (score 2):

The state value should be inside quotes. i-e:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tbl_zip WHERE abr = '"+ st +"'", con);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function PopulateCity. st needs to be in quotes.

Otherwise it will look for a column.

Like:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tbl_zip WHERE abr = " + "'" +  st + "'", con);
```